# How to add background color to a view with a NavigationStack?

Tags: swiftui, background, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to put a background color in this View, but apparently having NavigationStack prevents it from appearing. Is there any other way I can implement this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct DiscoverView: View {
    private let adaptiveColumns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 120))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.primaryApp.ignoresSafeArea(.all)

            NavigationStack {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumns, spacing: 60) {
                        ForEach(playlists) { playlist in
                            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                                PlaylistCardView(playlist: playlist)
                            }
                            .foregroundStyle(.primary)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm using in DiscoverView, if necessary I'll make other parts of the code available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just apply a background behind the `ScrollView`. So you probably don't need the `ZStack`:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        ScrollView {
            // content as before
        }
        .background(Color.primaryApp)
    }
}
```

Note that the safe areas are ignored by default when using this modifier. See [background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)).