# Modifying the background of views built with NavigationStack and Lists in SwitfUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-playground

NavigationtStack, combined with Lists and Sections makes building a native UI very easy in SwiftUI. Looking at Apple's own apps there are certain bits of flair which I am looking to achieve in my own app. Specifically by adding a background to the overall layout.

For reference, here are 3 of Apple's own apps with backgrounds behind what appears to be built with NavigationStack. When you scroll down the page, the title shrinks to the small navigation bar.

[image: Cropped screenshot of the Apple Health App]

The Apple Health app has a bloom/gradient backdrop that is static until a certain portion of the page has scrolled.

[image: Cropped screenshot of Apple Sports]

The Apple Sports app has a short gradient that does not appear to remain static at all (but hard to tell).

[image: Cropped screenshot of the Apple Home app]

The Apple Home app has an image that is a backdrop to the entire app.

What I have found with SwiftUI is that I can specifically change the colour of the navigation title area, either when shown in its entirety or when collapsed. This option only allows a solid colour, gradients or images cannot be applied.

When using `ZStack` I can stack a gradient behind the title section, but it then appears above the collapsed title when scrolling.

Trying to stack a rectangle and positioning higher up causes a visible separation between the rectangle and the following content (List in my case) which breaks the flow. The example below puts a rectangle with a gradient which is followed by a clear break before the NavigationStack is show. Using the position modifier only re-positions the rectangle in its own space.

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(LinearGradient(
        gradient: .init(colors: [.red, .blue]),
        startPoint: .init(x: 0, y: 0),
        endPoint: .init(x: 0, y: 1)
    ))
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .frame(height: 50)
NavigationStack {
    List {
        Section("", content: {
            Text("First Item")
        })
    }
    .toolbar {
        Button("Add") {}
    }
    .navigationTitle("Page Test")
    .toolbarBackground(.pink, for: .navigationBar)
    .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
    .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
}
```

This is the output of the code:

[image: Screenshot of vertically stacked elements in a Swift Playgrounds preview]

The answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77815849/how-to-add-background-color-to-a-view-with-a-navigationstack) points to placing ScrollView inside the Navigation Stack I encounter the same issue, just that the rectangle and List each take half of the screen and the NavigationStack title now sits on top of everything.

If I take the same code and wrap it in `ScrollView` instead, that causes the NavigationStack to appear off screen and it's inaccessible so you're left with a gradient on a blank screen.

[image: Screenshot of predominantly blank Swift Playground preview]

Wrapping with `ZStack` instead causes the gradient to be hidden behind the default background colour of the view. Rearranging so the rectangle is second causes it to sit above everything underneath it.

[image: Screenshot of items stacked on top of each other in a Swift Playgrounds preview]

Given the examples from Apple above, how can you customise a SwiftUI view that uses NavigationStack with either a defined colour, gradient or image as a background?

Comment: I would suggest using a ZStack with the gradient at the start of it and avoid using List because it has some problems, like: it exapand to fill all the screen with its background, and even using `.listStyle(.plain)` has its share of problems as far as I've seen. I can share some code if you want.